# Upgrade to JUnit 4 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I tried switching to JUnit 4 in Eclipse using the instructions in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25770299.

It basically says to remove any JUnit 3 library in the build path (I removed a JUnit 3.7 jar) and add the JUnit 4 library, which I did.

However, when I run the following code in my test class:

```
import junit.runner.Version;
System.out.println("JUnit version is: " + Version.id());
```

I get:

```
JUnit version is: 3.8.1
```

I don't have any other JUnit libraries in my buildpath.

If it's relevant, the exact Eclipse version is "Indigo Service Release 1, Build id: 20110916-0149".

How can I fix this and run JUnit 4?

Comment: Thanks, but in "run configurations" it's actually set on JUnit 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your manifest file to see if there is any dependencies left with junit 3.x
Also you could perform a search `junit` in your project and see which files hold a link to 3.x

Try clean/build your project in the end

Comment: Thanks! I searched for "junit" in the project and finally found some sh files referencing "junit-3.8.1.jar"

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading it is necessary to switch existing unit tests to junit4:

[image]